# change attribute of html element from angular component

Tags: angular, components

I have image in html part of component

```
<img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
```

and in ts file of component I have some function where I want to change image source.

```
 openDialog(): void {
change image source here!
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to bind the image url.

```
imageUrl = http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" class="avatar img-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar


 openDialog(): void {
   this.imageUrl = "new link"
 }
```

Html

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" alt="avatar">
```